Context api values reading NaN when used for calculation in a function but returns as a number when logged to the console individually
I'm trying to get the percent of a number using numbers gotten from an api endpoint which I saved globally using context api but each time I pass the number to the function doing the calculation it returns NaN but when I log the inputs used for the calculation on the console it shows the actual numbers.
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { FormatNum } from "../utils/FormatNum";
import { useFetchUsersData } from "../hooks/useFetchUsersData";

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const onError = (error) => {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  };

  const enabled = true;
  const endpoint = "growthData";
  const { data } = useFetchUsersData({ endpoint, enabled, onError });

  const totalUser = data?.data.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
    return accumulator + currentItem.users;
  }, 0);

  const totalActiveUsers = data?.data.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
    return accumulator + currentItem.activeUsers;
  }, 0);

  const [totalUsers, setNumberOfUsers] = useState(Number(totalUser));
  const [activeUsers, setActiveUsers] = useState(Number(totalActiveUsers));
  const [percentActiveUsers, setPercentActiveUsers] = useState(0);

  const calculatePercent = (total) => {
    console.log("value:", total);
    if (total && total > 0) {
      return (activeUsers / totalUsers) * 100;
    }
    return 0; // Return 0 if totalUsers is not valid or zero to avoid NaN
  };

  const updateNumberOfUsers = (newNumber) => {
    setNumberOfUsers(FormatNum(newNumber));
  };

  const updateActiveUsers = (newNumber) => {
    setActiveUsers(FormatNum(newNumber));
  };

  const updatePercentActiveUsers = (newNumber) => {
    setPercentActiveUsers(FormatNum(newNumber));
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        totalUsers,
        updateNumberOfUsers,
        activeUsers,
        updateActiveUsers,
        percentActiveUsers,
        updatePercentActiveUsers,
        calculatePercent,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Custom hook to use the UserContext
export const useUserContext = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};


This is were I'm passing in my data from because every other thing I tried didn't work
import React from "react";
import { HiOutlineUsers } from "react-icons/hi2";
import { useUserContext } from "../../context/usersData";
import ActiveUsersPieChart from "../Charts/ActiveUsersPieChart";

const ActiveUsersPieCard = () => {
  const {
    activeUsers,
    totalUsers,
    percentActiveUsers,
    updatePercentActiveUsers,
    calculatePercent,
  } = useUserContext();

  console.log(totalUsers);
  const percent = calculatePercent(totalUsers);
  updatePercentActiveUsers(Number(percent));
  console.log(percent);
  console.log(activeUsers);
  console.log(totalUsers);

  return (
    <div className="md:w-full md:h-[430px] flex flex-col bg-blue-800 shadow-md rounded-lg p-5">
      <section className="md:ml-4">
        <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
          <HiOutlineUsers size={20} />
          <h3 className="text-xl">Percentage of users active</h3>
        </div>
        <p className="text-2xl font-semibold mt-2 mb-5">{percentActiveUsers}</p>
      </section>

      <ActiveUsersPieChart />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ActiveUsersPieCard;



is it calculatePercent that returns NaN? it's the only place you console.log anything useful, but you console.log(total), but the calculation uses some other variables, so, how do you know (activeUsers / totalUsers) would produce a number? hint: you don't know

I guess that totalUsers and totalActive are zero because data hasn’t loaded when you compute them.

Try using an async function to wait for the data before performing the fn operation

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
